# Are irrational numbers prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I don't mean in the literal sense, but from the perspective of not having divisible integers

Comment: What is a "divisible integer'?

Comment: I believe he means, not divisible by any integers $n \neq 1$

Comment: The notion of prime is only defined for integers greater than one.

Comment: @coffeemath numbers like 1.5 are equal to $$2^1 * 3^-1$$ whereas numbers like Euler's constant can't be represented that way

Comment: mrnovice: If so, what is meant by "divisible"? are both factors required to be integers? If so answer clear.

Comment: script8man Do you mean in last comment that 1.5 is $3^1 \times 2^{-1}$?

Comment: @coffeemath sorry my mathjaxx is rusty

Comment: script8man I just meant the numerator of 1.5 should be 3 and denominator 2, but you had 2 in numerator.

Comment: This question would be more interesting in literal sense when it comes about structure of prime numbers and composition of irrationals.

Comment: @usir0 what's your take on the idea?

Comment: Take number 2 as an example. It is an even number with one of the properties of primes. In similar way irrational numbers can inherit structure of primes since all numbers can be thought as polynomials. I have to study it first to say more - it is just my first feeling.

Comment: Euler's constant is $(2e)*2^{-1}=(\frac e2)*2$ so yes it can.  Unless you mean both terms must be powers of intergers.  But don't call numbers like that "composite"; we call them "rational".  And we don't call numbers that can't be represented that way "prime"; we call them "irrational".

Comment: I voted to close this question while thinking about *prime* elements in a more abstract and general sense, which gives us more insight into the primality of an element and saves time from ambiguous discussions, in a ring $R$.  So what in which *ring* we're talking about?  Unlike the usual prime numbers, irrational numbers live outside $\Bbb Q$. I think it's more sensible to discuss in $\Bbb R$, which is a field, so it's a principal ideal, so every prime ideal is a maximal ideal, which doesn't exist in $\Bbb R$.  Thus there no prime ideal in $\Bbb R$, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Treating "prime" as meaning "not divisible by any integer other than $1$ and possibly itself", we have to decide what "divisible" means. Usually, we say that $n$ is divisible by $a$ if there is an *integer* $b$ so that $ab = n$. Under that interpretation, irrational numbers are certainly "prime", but so are all non-integers; remember that if $a$ and $b$ are both integers, so is $ab$.

However, we could also define "prime" as "divisible only by $1$ *and* itself". Then, for example, $\pi$ cannot be prime - while it isn't divisible by any integers other than $1$, it isn't divisible by itself either (under our definition of "divisible" above).

EDIT: You recently commented an observation that suggests another definition. If we count, for example, $3^{-1}$ for the purposes of divisibility, rational numbers are nonprime. So let's use this definition: $n$ is divisible by $a$ if there is some *integer power of an integer* $b$ so that $ab = n$. So, for example, $3/2$ is divisible by $3$ because $2^{-1}$ is an integer power of an integer. Under that definition, rational numbers are not prime, but irrational numbers are.

Unfortunately, then we have that *integers* are not prime. For example, $2$ is "divisible" by $4$, because $2 = 4 \cdot 2^{-1}$. So this definition of divisibility doesn't respect the usual one, unlike the previous candidate.

Comment: I think that any definition of a prime must specify that a prime must be an integer. Otherwise you arrive at things like $\pi$ isn't divisible by itself.

Comment: @mrnovice I just imagine a number line and think of all the numbers that can only be described using themselves, and I think that's at least conceptually similar

Comment: "Only described by themselves" is ultimately meaningless.  Let $a= \pi -e $ then $e=\pi - a $ describes $e $ without using $e $.  Or if $b =\pi/3e $ then $e =3*\pi b $.  Is that "prime" or not?